# map inside a map - Need data in specific format

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a requirement where I want to read multiple project pom files and  display data in  below format

```
  {
 "java" : {"1.7" : ["project1"],"1.8": ["project2"]},
 "junit" : {"4.12" : ["project1"]},
 "hsqldb" : {"1.8" : ["project3"],"1.1": ["project6"]}
   }
```

My coding is getting input on project , ver and technlogy and displaying, but however I couldnt second value inside the internal

```
private void addTechnologyData(String projName,String techName,String ver)
{
    String keyFormat=techName;
    if (technologyMap.containsKey(keyFormat)) {
        Map preValue=technologyMap.get(keyFormat);
        if(!preValue.containsValue(projName)) {
            Map<String,String> temp = new HashMap();
            temp=preValue;
            temp.put(ver,projName);
            technologyMap.put(keyFormat, temp);
        }
    } else {
       Map<String,String> projectVersiomap = new HashMap();
       projectVersiomap.put(ver,projName);
       technologyMap.put(keyFormat, projectVersiomap);
    }
}
```

Please help me understand why I couldnt add 2nd  key value pair to Internal map?
Is there a better way than what Im doing?

Comment: Tips: first get the map for the technology (if contains, get. If not create and insert). Then insert the new value into that map.

Comment: I am worried by the array for the project name on a version. I would guess you can find multiple project on java 1.7. So you need a `Map<String,Map<String, List<String>>>` or you get ride of that and create a `List<Technology>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you are expecting more than one project per version (since you have an array), so your `Map` is preventing this, you can only have one value per key. You can use a `List` like `Map<String,Map<String, List<String>>>` but I would suggest to use some POJO to keep the code cleaner.

Create a `Technology` class that will hold a list of `Project` for each version in a `Map`. This would look like :

```
public class Technology{

    private String name;
    private Map<String, List<Project>> projects;

    public Technology(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.projects = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addProjectToVersion(String version, Project project){
        List<Project> l = this.projects.get(version);
        if(l == null){ //doesn't exist
            l = new ArrayList<>();
            this.projects.put(version, l);
        }
        l.add(project);
    }
}
```

Here, the logic is in the POJO. You just need to use a `Collection` to hold your instance, a `Map` if you like, or a `List` (implement `equals` and `hashCode` to recover easily the instance). And you can use it like :

```
private Map<String, Technology> techs = new HashMap<>();
....
public void addProject(String tech, String version, String projectName){
    Technology t = techs.get(tech);
    if(t == null){ //doesn't exist
         t = new Technology(tech);
         techs.put(tech, t);
    }
    t.addProjectToVersion(version, new Project(projectName));
}

public void insertData(){
    addProject("java", "1.7", "project1");
    addProject("java", "1.7", "project2");
    addProject("java", "1.8", "project1");
    addProject("junit", "4.12", "project1");

    System.out.println(techs);
}
```

This will input correctly :

> {junit={4.12=[project1]}, java={1.7=[project1, project2], 1.8=[project1]}}

Note that I reused your logic, based on the requirements it could be better to have a `List<Project>` holding each `Technology` with the version. But this is based on the context.